# Cannot import OUTLET from Storyboard to ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, xcode13

I try to CTRL CLICK DRAG my view from my storyboard. My class is well set as viwcontroller for the view cannot be imported as outlet...
Any Help ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Ok , just need to close Xcode , or clean build , to makes a re indexation , and you can do it again... Xcode 13 bug i think.